# If $f(x)g(x)$ tends to infinity and $f(x)$ tends to $0$, is there a proposition that states that $g(x)$ must tend to infinity?

Tags: limits

I know it is somewhat evident however I need a proposition or theorem that definitively states this

I.e if $f(x)g(x) \to \infty$ and $f(x)\to 0$ then $|g(x)| \to \infty$

EDIT: I have changed the question to $|g(x)|$, thank you.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, very good point. However what if I alter this to |g(x)|?

Comment: Yes, so then |g(x)| would tend to infinity? Here as (-1)^(floor x) would be equal to one due to the absolute values?

Answer (score 1):

Please do NOT change the question after there is an answer.

For the case $x \to \infty$, suppose $f(x)g(x) \to \infty$ and $f(x) \to 0$.

Then for any $M>0$, there exists some $X_1 \in \mathbb R$ such that $f(x)g(x) > M$ for all $x > X_1$.

With this restriction we must infer that $f(x) \ne 0$ for all $x > X_1$.

Furthermore, taking $\epsilon = 1$, we can find $X_2 \in \mathbb R$ such that $|f(x) - 0| < 1$ for all $x > X_2$.

Take $X = \max (X_1, X_2)$. Then for any $x > X$:

$$|g(x)| = \left|\frac {f(x)g(x)}{f(x)}\right|> \frac M1=M$$

which shows that indeed $g(x) \to \infty$.

The case for $x\to c\in\mathbb R$ is exceeding similar. Can you finish that proof by yourself?

Comment: Yes thank you and apologies it is my first time posting